# __saturatef() intrinsic has no double-precision equivalent

Tags: cuda

Cuda supports [intrinsic functions](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#intrinsic-functions). Some map to device instructions, like fused multiply-adds, that cannot be expressed in normal syntax. Others are approximations that supposed to be faster (though potentially less accurate) than "standard" functions.

It seems that the latter type of intrinsic is not supported for double-precision arguments, and only for single-precision floats. Makes sense: if you are using doubles, you are by definition interested in accuracy over speed.

To my surprise, however, the `__saturatef()` intrinsic, which clamps its argument between zero and one, does not have a double-precision version.

Is there any potential loss of data if I use the `__saturatef()` intrinsic over a naive implementation? If so, does anybody know how this intrinsic works? If not, why would nvidia leave out the double-precision version?

Comment: What do you mean by "potential loss of data"? Can you give an example? The primary purpose of CUDA's device intrinsics is to expose some hardware capabilities not otherwise accessible. Hardware provides saturation for single-precision arithmetic because of relevant use cases, it does *not* provide saturation for double-precision arithmetic. The question as-is is borderline off-topic. I would suggest rephrasing the question so it is clearly about programming. For example: Given that there is no double-precision intrinsic `__saturate(double)`, what is the fastest way to emulate this operation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of CUDA's device function intrinsics is to expose particular hardware capabilities that are not otherwise accessible, e.g. fast approximations to some algebraic and transcendental functions, or clamping to the interval [0,1] in the case of `__saturatef()`, which maps to GPU's machine instruction `F2F{.FTZ}.F32.F32.SAT` for compute capabilities prior to 5.0 (`sm_50)` and `FADD.SAT` for architectures greater than, or equal to, compute capability 5.0.

A look at the [PTX documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html) shows that floating-point saturation is supported for half-precision (`.f16`) and single-precision (`.f32`) operations, but not for double-precision (`.f64`) operations. So the non-orthogonality of the provided intrinsics is caused by non-orthogonality in the GPU hardware. Saturation is provided for lower precisions because of relevant use cases, including graphics, which typically do not use double precision.

A quick exhaustive test shows that `__saturatef (float)` behaves identical to `fminf (fmaxf (float, 0.0f), 1.0f)`. Looking at disassembled code, it also seems that the CUDA compiler will treat this min / max idiom identical to the use of `__saturatef()`, as an optimization. Therefore, a double-precision equivalent can be created easily as

```
double my_saturate (double a)
{
    return fmin (fmax (a, 0.0), 1.0);
}
```